# WinEdt Tree to the right

Tags: winedt

Is there any way to move the tree panel in Winedt to the right?

By default it is in the left side, and I am wondering how one can move it to the right side?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there is. Follow these steps:

1. Show the "Options Interface" (Options -> Options Interface)

   [image]
2. Double-click the "Forms" item in the "Application" branch (`Forms.ini` gets opened)
3. Locate the line

   ```
   TREE="Tree"
   ```

   and just below this one change the line

   ```
     DOCKED=3
   ```

   to

   ```
     DOCKED=4
   ```
4. Press <kbd>Shift+Ctrl+F9</kbd>

That's it. Now the Tree panel is docked on the right side.